# Understanding this Abstract Algebra Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> If $E$ is an extension field of $F$, $\alpha \in E$ is algebraic over $F$, and $\beta \in F(\alpha)$, then deg($\beta, F$) divides deg($\alpha, F$).

I know that deg($\alpha$, $F$) is the degree of the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$ (and similarly for $\beta$). But what does it mean for $\beta$ to be in $F(\alpha$), and what exactly is this theorem saying? Thank you.

Comment: Consider an example: $\beta = \sqrt 2$, $\alpha = \sqrt[6] 2$.

Comment: $F(\alpha)$ is the sub-field of $E$ generated by $F\cup \{\alpha\}$, which is the smallest (in terms of subsets) subfield of $E$ that has $F\cup \{\alpha\}$ as a subset.  Equivalently $F(\alpha)$ is the common intersection of all subfields of $E$ that have $F\cup \{\alpha\}$ as a subset, Every member of  $F(\alpha\}$ is equal to $p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$ for some polynomials $p, q$ that have  all co-efficients in $F.$ If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ then every member of $F(\alpha)$ is $p(\alpha)$ for some polynomial $p$ with co-efficients in $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $\deg_F\alpha=[F(\alpha):F]$,  $\deg_F\beta=[F(\beta):F]$ and
$$[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]\cdot[F(\beta):F]$$

Comment: So what does it mean for $\beta \in F(\alpha)$?

Comment: The degree of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is a divisor of the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.